# CSS relative position acts different on different pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been trying to debug a web site to speed it up. I search a plugin in wordpress and I found **Autoptimizer** and decided to use it. After **minifying CSS files and inline CSS files**, some bug appeared in the blog. I saw that web pages act like they are on **mobile-view** mode except index.php so home page. I do not know how to solve it and I could not fix it.

This is the [homepage](https://www.finahukuk.com/) of wordpress website. As you see footer is good positioned. But when you check the other pages such as [this one](https://www.finahukuk.com/ihracat-ve-ar-ge-tesvikleri/), it is aligned like I open the web page in a mobile device. Not only footer but all body parts, elements, classes act like they are in a mobile device.

I deactivated the CSS options of AutoOptimizer but afterwards some HTML elements got broken. That's why I re-activated the plugin and thought this problem (instead of some broken tags) can be solvable than other one.

**Please help me.** I think sharing CSS codes is unnecessary because you can display them easily with dev options in browser. Even I compared their container classes. I try to find differences between container div in index.php and container div in other pages but they are the **same** classes and have same attributes.

Comment: @babbitt I didn't *add* any tag. I removed an irrelevant one

Comment: Okay I removed the unnecessary tags.

Comment: Autoptimizer broke your CSS, sometimes the homepage is left out of the minifying cycle. If i look at your minified files I see a difference within the two pages. Remove the plugin, remove your browser/server cache and maybe try another plugin like Hummingbird. Your HTML wasn´t broken, I think you saw a chached version.

Comment: @ArnoTenkink yes homepage and other pages have different css files. It is horrifying me to see broken web page. I'm deactivating right now could you check it for me please?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Apologies, the history can make changes hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `float, margin-right`, and `position` on the other pages footer in element with class `one-fourth` from what I can tell. Seems like you forgot to load a stylesheet to me.

Edit:

Did some further review and it seems like you're missing the following styling for the class `one-fourth` in your footer:

```
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-right: 4%;
width: 22%;
```

Comment: Honestly there may be other attributes missing here too, those are just the ones I saw immediately

Comment: You mean style.css file right? After minifying they kinda disappear. Which div should I put these css attributes?

Comment: Can you check .ultimax-wrapper in css? It affects the whole body of the content.

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş From what I can tell (I'm just looking at footer) it seems that the difference between the two pages is that one has these attributes in `.one-fourth` and the other does not. These are both located in the `5pxpl.css` file but they seem to differ across pages. Maybe that's the root of your issue?

Comment: I'm going to check right now and try to add the code snippet you gave me. Thanks for your support I hope it will fix my issue :(

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş If it works for you make sure to mark the answer as correct so that people searching for something similar will be more likely to find this. Also in future I recommend staying away from lond-winded explanations and saying things like "no need to add code" Generally SO is not a great place to get people to do the debugging for you, it's more helpful if you come to SO with a problem for which you have no solution. This question is moreso suited to a wordpress forum. nbd though :)

Comment: Thanks dude you are nice to me. I will add code snippets and probably make it as bounty reward question.

Comment: You were right. When I add the codes you shared, one column aligned like the one in index.php. Now I am going to find a way to make it dynamically :) Thank you dude!

Comment: Np :) happy I can help. CSS is one of those things where debugging doesn't really exist so it can be tricky